# How does one add something to the end of an url with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to add *?lang=English* to an url */self-service/more here* if a visitor comes from a specific domain. (not comes from, thats impossible but i meant was first at site A and then clicked a link and went to my site)
How can i do that? I tried reading the manual but its actually a bit over my head

Comment: Visitors do not “come from” domains.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for taking the time to pointme on my mistake.                Did u really not understand what i meant? It must be the difference between tech and non tech users. Thanks anyway for whatever your drive is. People indeed dont come from domains, what i meant was that a visitor may come from a other website to ours. U must call that a refering website, if not please let me know. I think the majority understood that, but thanks for your response

Comment: Being precise in what is being talked about is a necessity when talking about technical issues, whether the layman likes it or not. And since there _are_ many people who actually think that where a visitor “comes from” could be determined _reliably_ – and wrongly so – this needed pointing out (if not for your sake, then for those who find this question afterwards).

Comment: If you want to make that decision based on a specific referrer (or referring domain), then you can write a rule that does so (in combination with a `RewriteCond`). However, there are more and more circumstances where you will _not_ get any referrer at all – for example when the referring site was accessed via HTTPS. And besides that, the mere fact that I found the link to your page on a specific 3rd party site does not in fact say much about what _my_ actual language preferences might be – so “Content Negotiation” is something you should rather look into, then the referrer.

Comment: Its an other site of mine where the people click the link, i need to be able to know that they came from there so i can direct them to the page they want in English language. It cant be done via browser language or smth in this case

Comment: I guess i needed to explain the specific circumstances, but the question would get long by doing that.

Comment: If it’s another page of yours, then you are in control of what the link looks like in the first place – so you should add the parameter there already, that would be much more reliable than any referrer check.

Comment: Dear CBroe, no i am not or may choose not to be in this case. That there may be better ways in your perception does not answer anything. As u dont understand the situation, and u are not to blame, your answers maybe wrong. The question is clear, and i want to leave out as much variables as i can. So stating that i have control or not does not seem to be an answer to my question. U cant asume that i am anything, not even in control. But thanks for your time.

Comment: U maybe right and i could change that link via an other method,i tried and tried but as this is smth i almost understand, i would want to try it this way. Can i have that freedom and the freedom to ask about it? It will definitly teach me a lot.

Comment: _“as this is smth i almost understand”_ – if you “almost” understand this, then why is there no example of _anything_ you have tried in that regard contained within your question?

Comment: Dear CBroe, im sorry i should have known who i was dealing with. ill make u happy: U are right, and if u did not get it: U are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the mix of rewrite condition and rewrite rule like this, placed on top of .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(http|https)://best-graphic-design\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?lang=English  [R=301,L,QSA]
```

A simple explanation

First check for the referer to your site, NC flag stands for nocase/ignore case

If condition matches, redirect to desired location, in your case, same host while appending the new parameter, flags used here are R - Redirect, L - Last, QSA - Query String Append.

Hope it finally helps.

Comment: updated answer after reading comments, also keep in mind the comments from CBroe

Comment: It does not seem to work (( My site is at snelgoedkoop.nl, the English domain for that is best-graphic-design.co.uk. As the ordering part of both sites is at snelgoedkoop.nl and i cant change it, i want visitors that click http://best-graphic-design.co.uk/en/self-service/account/cart.php%3Fgid=13.html and now go to http://www.snelgoedkoop.nl/self-service/account/cart.php/?a=add&pid=26 to arive at http://www.snelgoedkoop.nl/self-service/account/cart.php/?a=add&pid=26&language=English

Comment: It worked!!  Thanks for understanding what i meant, but thats easy for a techhie user ))) And thanks for the guidance, i wish there where more of u on earth..

Comment: I was happy too soon )) If u could help me i would be really thankfull.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. It added an extra www. in front but i removed that. It may need some tweaking but i can manage that now from looking at the example. Many thanks